# Any way to get P4V to work with older servers?

Tags: perforce

I use P4V as a Perforce client. I updated to 2009.1 to get some major bug fixes, and it seems they removed the ability to connect to older clients. I do work for a few clients, and 5/6 depots I have to work with are new, but one is older (2002.2 I think). Does this mean that not only I can't get any more bug fixes because 1 of 6 servers is old, but now I'm completely locked out of that server since the older P4V clients are no longer online?

I know the 2007.x version I used before works with the old servers, but I can't find it online. Please tell me I'm not SOL... The Visual Studio integration is part of the P4V package, *not* the P4Win package, so if something isn't fixed I might never have VS support for P4 again. Help :(

Comment: You might get better response to this on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Have you contacted support at Perforce? I haven't used it in a while but when we were using Perforce support was always excellent.

Answer (score 2):

You can find previous perforce releases at the following url:
ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install P4V to get the Visual Studio plugin. It's included with P4V, yes, but you can certainly install it separately:

 http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4scc.html

P4SCC is what does the Visual Studio integration.

Comment: If you follow the download link, you'll see it's labeled "Included in the P4V Installer" and the download is `p4vinst.exe` (P4V). Either way, it doesn't address the fact that they removed support for their servers from the clients.